# Handling 404 error and show static html with Express 4

Tags: node.js, express

I'm spinning up a server with Express:

```
let BASE = process.env.BASE || '/app'
let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
let server = express()

server.use(BASE, express.static(__dirname + BASE, {
  etag: false,
  extensions: ['html']
}))

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  plugins.util.log(`Server: http://localhost:${PORT}${BASE}`)
  done()
})
```

Everything works like a charm, but **how can I handle the 404 errors**?
I'd like to simply render an `html` page placed in the root, without using any template engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to add this as your **last** route

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).sendFile('error.html', {root: publicPath});
});
```

publicPath is the folder where you got your static files.